# Filezilla downloads failing for specific range of filesize?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I've been working with Filezilla at my work for a while now without any major issues, except this one.

Conditions:

- Some issue causes file downloads to fail, since I have Filezilla set to automatically overwrite files without prompt, this sends the program into an infinite loop of attempting to download the file. I then have to cancel the queue; this results in the local copy of the file being made empty.
- It occurs only with files of a size 7-8ish KBs. Files less than 7000 Bytes are (I think) never effected by this bug, and files 8000 Bytes or over transfer just fine as well.
- This occurs only on download, not upload.
- It appears to only happen in Filezilla, have tried a couple of other FTP solutions and did not get the same results.
- It occurs in bulk, recursive, and single downloads.

My co-worker has been having the same problem, so I don't think this is an issue with my computer, but I have no idea if it's a rare Filezilla bug or an issue with some setting on our server.

If anyone has a similar experience or solution, I would be very grateful to hear from you.

Edited to include the log when encountering the issue:

```
Status: Starting download of .../file-name.php
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx,xx)
Command:    RETR file-name.php
Response:   150-Accepted data connection
Response:   150 7.6 kbytes to download
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  Transfer connection interrupted: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Response:   226-File successfully transferred
Response:   226 0.000 seconds (measured here), 38.81 Mbytes per second
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 7,939 bytes in 1 second
```

This will loop infinitely and get me nowhere.